# Why isn't jekyll showing comments?

Tags: github, jekyll, pull-request

Why isn't jekyll showing comments?

I have the code:

```html
{% if site.data.comments[page.slug] %}
<h3>
{% if site.data.comments[page.slug].size > 1 %}
{{ site.data.comments[page.slug] | size }}
{% endif %}
Komentarze:
</h3>
{% assign comments = site.data.comments[page.slug] | sort %}
{% for comment in comments %}
<label>
<strong>{{ comment[1].name }}</strong>
</a>
</label>
<em>{{ comment[1].date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}</em>
<p>{{ comment[1].message | markdownify }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action="{{ site.staticman_url }}">
<h3>Napisz komentarz:</h3>
<input name="options[redirect]" type="hidden" value="{{ post.url }}">
<input name="options[slug]" type="hidden" value="{{ page.slug }}">
<label>Imię (Wyświetlane, wymagane)</label>
<input name="fields[name]" type="text" required placeholder="Jan Kowalski" title="To pole jest wymagane">
<label>E-mail (Ukryte, wymagane)</label>
<input name="fields[email]" type="email" required placeholder="jan@kowalski.com" title="To pole jest wymagane">
<label>Wiadomość (Wyświetlane, wymagane)</label>
<textarea style="width:100%" name="fields[message]" rows="5" required placeholder="Twoja wiadomość" title="To pole jest wymagane"></textarea>
<p>Komentarze pojawią się po zaakceptowaniu przez moderatora.</p>
<button type="submit">Wyślij komentarz</button>
</form>
```

Which works, comments are sent to the staticman-app and I get a pull request, I click accept in the repository the comment file appears correctly, but why does this code not show the comment itself? I can't even see it in `.html` (so it's not CSS's fault), I've been working on it for several hours and I can't find a solution. For more questions please write a comment :)

Comment: Please post a couple of comments as it exists in the data file. (You may swap the text with dummy content if so desired). Also, seeing the rendered HTML from the above code will be helpful.

Comment: The html code shows only the comment form itself, it does not show the rendered comments, please go to https://github.com/IgorKowalczyk/blog/tree/master/_data/comments for a sample comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot below, it looks like the comments are rendered as expected..

---

[image: Screenshot of post showing comments]

Comment: But i fix the problem, i no have time to write here, but... i have new problem the comments are showed in all blog posts.